# Having multiple statuslines in Vim

Tags: vim, macvim

Is it possible to have multiple lines of statusline? Like in one line I will have file info, and in the line below have cursor info.

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`vim-jp` (Japanese vim user group) is writing patch for this just now.

https://github.com/vim-jp/issues/issues/225

Patch is here:

https://gist.github.com/3158492

[image]

Comment: For everyone out there, this patch works. But you can wait until it gets into official Vim if you want. If that happens of course.

Comment: @Eduan this patch don't pass all tests yet. patch maintainer is working to fix it. we will post this patch to vim-dev if the problem is fixed. please wait.

Comment: How do I use this patch?